# Is B pin of BJT always in the middle

Tags: transistors, identification

Is B pin of BJT always in the middle of three pins of the plastic and metal casing kind of BJT, or only in either one, or it's not?

Comment: You need to go through the datasheet of the part no. mentioned in the body of the given transistor.

Comment: This is impossible to answer, as there have been trends so far but the future may change the answer completely. Voting to close as opinion answers. The answer is 'no', by the way.

Comment: Collector is often in the middle in in-line packages, as it's the substrate connection. Read the datasheet, carefully. Some SOT23 transistors can be had in an -R version, which is a mirror image of the normal pinout, to aid layout in certain mixer and current mirror structures.

Comment: BCE, EBC CBE ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sometimes the base is on one side instead of in the middle position. It is important to know the exact part number. With a data sheet of the transistor you can desume the position of its electrodes.

Comment: EXACT part number. Famously the BC214 and BC214L were different...

Answer (score 3):

No; for example, the [2SC1815](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Micro%20Commercial%20PDFs/2SC1815-x.pdf):

[image: 2SC1815 pinout]